# Flex Tree/Branch Diagramming/Graphics

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, diagramming, uicomponents

I was wondering if anyone had access to source code that would allow me to draw lines between objects. I have examples of the standard one line between 2 objects.

What I'm looking for is an example of how to draw a branching line. I.e. Starts as a line coming from an object and then branches out to other objects. I don't want to draw multiple lines from the same object because I need the objects to be related and the lines to have a settable property.

The added issue is that I want the number of branches available to be settable by the user. But if I can find code that dooes the branching lines, it probably wouldnt be too hard to tweek.

Hopefully what I'm looking for makes sense. Any hints and tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the graphing libraries:

- Birdeye's [RaVis](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html#) and [Source](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ravis/libRaVis/org/un/cava/birdeye/ravis/graphLayout/layout)
- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo) and [Source](http://flare.prefuse.org/)

Best,
Lance

Comment: These all have multiple lines coming from one node and what I need is one line coming from a node and the branching out into several. They do however, have exellent examples of how to animate and reconfigure nodes. So thanks for that. 

What I may end up doing is using multiple lines coming from one node and add properties to the fromNode and toNode to allow me to validate values of the nodes/lines. E.g the sum of node probability values must sum to one.